# How can I detect the user has clicked on the Page Tab where my html page is?

Tags: javascript, events, focus, window, document

I'm developing a web chat and I need to raise an event when the conversation has changed so the page title changes so one user can know that the other user has written anything.

So I tried the code:

```
addEvent(window,'focus',function(){ alert(1); } );
```

and
    addEvent(document,'focus',function(){ alert(2); } );

but it does not work.

I need the event to be raised **even if the user does not click** on the web page.

For that event, I've got the solutions:

```
<body onclick="showClickedElement(this);" >
```

Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this code that works for IE6, 7,8 and firefox and no not need Jquery.

```
function onBlur() {
document.body.className = 'blurred';
```

};
function onFocus(){
    document.body.className = 'focused';
};

if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}

[source](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus)

Comment: hi. thanks for the code. works in firefox but it didn't work in IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

taken from: http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2010/04/25/tab-visible-event/

```
var timer = null;
function tabVisible() {
    if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
    window.onfocus = null;
    window.onmouseover = null;
    /* your code to dispatch event here */
}
// Firefox, IE8
window.onfocus = tabVisible;
// Safari
window.onmouseover = tabVisible;
// dirty hack for Chrome
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' Chrome/') != -1) {
    function dirtyChromePoll() {
        if (window.screenX || window.screenY) tabVisible();
    }
    timer = setInterval(dirtyChromePoll, 100);
}
```

If it doesn't work with your addEvent, you might want to try jQuery (see [Event for when user switches browser tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038643/event-for-when-user-switches-browser-tabs))

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    // Do Blur Actions Here
});
$(window).focus(function(e) {
    // Do Focus Actions Here
});
```