# Is it possible to detect right before the user changes tabs/minimizes?

Tags: javascript

I know it's possible to detect [right before a user closes a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page) using `onbeforeunload`. I was just wondering if there was a similar event fired right before the user switches tabs or minimizes. I'm **not looking** for an event that fires after the user changes tabs.

Is this possible?

Comment: Ah, the fictitious `beforeblur` event. ;-p

Comment: **Related:** http://stackoverflow.com/q/1038643/560648 (not a dup, though)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I saw another one like that. I guess I'll have to make do with that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe that's possible.

Comment: @RayCheng Just throw an alert to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such event. Sorry!