# Event for when user switches browser tabs ONLY ONCE

Tags: jquery, logic, business-logic

I was looking at a functionality like this shown [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038643/event-for-when-user-switches-browser-tabs) .

But needed a slight change. 
Onfucus the function inside should run only once

```
    var flag=true;
    $(window).focus(function(e) {
        // Do Focus Actions Here
if(flag){
 func();
}

    });

function func(){ flag=false; }
```

Hey, actually i was looking for a similar kind of functionality. $(window).focus(function(e) { // Do Focus Actions Here}); The content inside focus will run every time when there is some other ajax functionality in the page, But one small change, 1. Is it possible to run the code inside this ONLY ONCE, when the user navigates back and forth between the same page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).focus(function(e) {
    // Do Focus Actions Here
    $(window).unbind('focus');
});
```

try this :)