# How to identify when a user switches tab in jsp

Tags: jsp, event-handling, jsp-tags

I am making a program that is for a test. it uses a combination of jsp and servlet and using tomcat 7.0 . My requirement is to identify whenever the user switches the tab or opens a new window of the browser, so that he is unable to use any other resources while giving the test.
I am planning to start a thread that continuously checks the focus of the user. What is the possible solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038643/event-for-when-user-switches-browser-tabs

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD the solution that the above question provides uses frameworks which I don't want to use

Answer (score 0):

window.onblur works

```
<script>
    window.onblur = function() { 
    //your code
     };
    </script>
```

jQuery implementations:

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    // your code
});
```