# Detect window not focused or tab switch with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to detect when the user switches a tab in order to change the title area when they receive a new chat message with "x new messages"

I tried:

```
var isActive;    
window.onfocus = function(){  isActive = true;   };     
window.onblur = function(){   isActive = false;  };
```

This does not work for me. Also, it doesn't have to be tabs, I want to make sure it detects that the specific window is not focused then 'do something'.

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE jQuery or Mootools for detecting

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    // Do Blur Actions Here
});
$(window).focus(function(e) {
    // Do Focus Actions Here
});
```

source: [Event for when user switches browser tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038643/event-for-when-user-switches-browser-tabs)