# Javascript Event Listener for switching back to window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

How do I make an event listener that runs when you switch back to a window?

I've tried "focus", but it only runs when you click inside a form on the window. 
How do I make it run every time you tab back to the window?

Here's my current code I'm running:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("focus", getURL, true);

    function getURL(){    
        //code
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: See [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953342/detect-window-not-focused-or-tab-switch-with-jquery/25953401#25953401) how you'd do it in jQuery:

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    // Do Blur Actions Here
});
$(window).focus(function(e) {
    // Do Focus Actions Here
});
```