# onTab Change event in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any onTab change event in javascript . Like whenwver the user is moved to new tab then an event is fired .

I have tried onfocus , onblur ,add listener but they are behaving differently in different  browser.
So is there any event that can be created when the tab is changed in java script ?

I tried the following links

[Event for when user switches browser tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038643/event-for-when-user-switches-browser-tabs)

Also tried the 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

but again the events are not proper

Answer (score 0):

The focus/blur events should work, 
but I suggest you listen on window and not document (if you did):

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus, 1);
    window.addEventListener('blur', onBlur, 1);
} else {
    // For IEs older than IE10
    document.attachEvent('onfocusin', onFocus);
    document.attachEvent('onfocusout', onBlur);
}
```

If this really doesn't work, the [Page Visibility API should be covered](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility) enough and work properly. If you want to support some older browsers or just want to make sure to cover all possible cases, I recommend you use [visibly.js by Addy Osmani](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/1122546).